# Is an outlet with a switched neutral dangerous?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, light-fixture, neutral

I have a switch that control the outlet at my home. The outlet is located on the ceiling of a room. The switch opens/closes the neutral line (not hot).

How dangerous is this for a house? I plan to remove the outlet, and simply connect a light bulb.

The switch should still turn on/off the light but not sure if switching the neutral line on/off is a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is against code but not *necessarily* all that dangerous. The classic problem is that when you are changing a light bulb, if hot is switched off then the socket is totally dead. If neutral is switched instead then hot is still present in the socket and a short from hot to ground will complete a circuit. Of course, similar problems can happen with a circuit where hot and neutral are reversed, which is often found in the wild (or at least in my old house...), so for anything beyond a simple light bulb replacement (which should be trivial and safe, as long as the bulb is not stuck or broken), the proper procedure is to turn off the breaker and not rely on the switch for safety.

However, it should be relatively easy to fix. There are some really wacky scenarios, but the two *likely* situations should be easy to fix. In both cases, replacing a receptacle with a hardwired light fixture makes no difference - the problem and solution are the same either way.

##### Existing Scenario 1: Power -> Receptacle -> Switch (aka Switch Loop)

Power hot and neutral go to receptacle box. Hot connects to the receptacle directly. Neutral connects to a wire going to the switch. Another wire comes back from the switch to the neutral connection of the receptacle.

In this case, changing how the wires are connected in the receptacle box will solve the problem.

##### Existing Scenario 2: Power -> Switch -> Receptacle

Power hot and neutral go to switch box. Switch is connected to neutral wire. Hot is connected to a hot wire going to the receptacle. The other connection on the switch is connected to a neutral wire going to the receptacle.

Similar to the first scenario, changing how the wires are connected in the switch box should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is where the danger lies:

If you or someone else decides to replace the plug with a light fixture, you might turn the switch off & go test the plug with a voltmeter.  You insert the probes into the slots and you get no voltage reading.  The average person would assume that means it is safe to handle the wires, but it isn't because all the switch disconnected is the neutral.

What you have at that point is a hot (black) wire that is still hot.  But also, if there is a load connected to the outlet (such as a lamp) the neutral on the outlet is also hot because it is no longer bonded to the neutral bar in the breaker panel.

That is a real danger, which is why the NEC does not allow it.

Situations like this are the reason you should always  test wires with a multimeter or probe type volt meter, then test them again with a non-contact voltage detector before handling them.  The non-contact detector detects the electromagnetic field produced by AC voltage.  It does not need a neutral.

I suggest getting an electrician to wire it properly.  If you are an electrician, but don't know for sure how to change the connections, a new question that includes details of the wires in each box will probably get you the information you need to make it right.

Regarding electricity, if you aren't sure, it's always best to ask first.